# Why is the maximum number of nodes in a binary search tree of height 'h' equal to 2^(h+1) - 1?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

We are currently learning about trees in my data structures class. One of my homework questions asks: "Show that the maximum number of nodes in a binary tree of height h is 2^(h+1) - 1". The hint my teacher gave us is to use the log statement.

I'm not looking for someone to give me a solution but I was hoping maybe someone could give me a better explanation of how Binary Trees and the logarithmic function are related. I'm confused as to where to even begin with this problem.

Comment: Logarithmic functions are related because at each level of a full binary tree there are twice as many nodes than on the previous one.

Comment: Usually this is an example problem to show how proof by induction is useful. That'd be the route I'd go here. But this is more of a discrete math problem than a programming problem. You'd have better luck on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Alex Allain wrote a whole chapter about binary trees in his book "Jump to c++" https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html

Found nowhere a better explaination

Comment: @scohe001 Yes it helped a little bit, I'm still trying to understand how I would go about writing a proof for it though.